# Get Every Url Directory

Tags: c#, url

I want to list every directory and subdirectory in a url, similar to Directory.GetFiles, but with a url. For example if I had the website https://www.website.com/, a list might look like

```
https://www.website.com/something
https://www.website.com/something/somethingElse
https://www.website.com/anotherthing/
https://www.website.com/thisthing/
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: That entirely depends on how that website handles URLs and what they map to.  URLs are not a file system.  "List every directory in a URL" doesn't make sense.  If your website happens to map URLs directly to a backing file system structure then just list the directories in the file system on the website, no need to involve the website at all.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? They look like "directories" but they may not be, take PHP and URL redirects for instance, which are widely used. Those may just redirect to calls to a PHP page. The only way to find those "directories" is to crawl the site, there is no "dir" command for web sites.

Comment: Ok. I didnt really think it would work but I guess it was worth a shot